# Json converting List cast error

Tags: c#, list, json.net, deserialization

I'm currently working on WinRT app and an API self hosted in a service, the service seems to work great.

I'm working with json to tranfer my data. i have no problem to serialize the instance of the class i want to transfer but the problems come when i want to deserializer.

Here the class :

```
public class DtoDirectory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<string> DirectoryIcon { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the helper i wrote to manipulate the JSON

```
public class SerializeHelper
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string value) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
            return ret;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static string Serialize<T>(T type) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(type);
            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Data when it comes from the API:

```
"[{"Name":"ANNONCES LEGALES","Path":"C:\\Test\\ANNONCES LEGALES","DirectoryIcon":["C:\\Test\\ANNONCES LEGALES\\fond.png","C:\\Test\\ANNONCES LEGALES\\icon.png"]},{"Name":"CONSEIL MUNICIPAL","Path":"C:\\Test\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL","DirectoryIcon":["C:\\Test\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\\fond.png","C:\\Test\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\\icon.png"]},{"Name":"DIVERS","Path":"C:\\Test\\DIVERS","DirectoryIcon":["C:\\Test\\DIVERS\\fond.png","C:\\Test\\DIVERS\\icon.png"]},{"Name":"ELECTIONS","Path":"C:\\Test\\ELECTIONS","DirectoryIcon":["C:\\Test\\ELECTIONS\\fond.png","C:\\Test\\ELECTIONS\\icon.png"]},{"Name":"ETAT CIVIL","Path":"C:\\Test\\ETAT CIVIL","DirectoryIcon":["C:\\Test\\ETAT CIVIL\\fond.png","C:\\Test\\ETAT CIVIL\\icon.png"]},{"Name":"URBANISME","Path":"C:\\Test\\URBANISME","DirectoryIcon":["C:\\Test\\URBANISME\\fond.png","C:\\Test\\URBANISME\\icon.png"]}]"
```

Finally the errors:

```
{"Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[DTO.DtoDirectory]."}
Error converting value to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[DTO.DtoDirectory]'. Path '', line 1, position 1027.
```

EDIT:

the code where i call the deserializer :

```
try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/api/document/ListDirectoryRoot?pathDirecory=C:\\Test\\Chasse");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
            var res = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var test = SerializeHelper.Deserialize<Wrapper >(lol);
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

public class Wrapper
{
  public List<DtoDirectory> list {get;set;}
 }
```

I unfortunately didn't succeed to figure out the error ..
Thanks for helping !

Comment: Can you add to your question the code where you actually use/invoke the SerializeHelper method?

Comment: And what's the `Wrapper` ? Could you please also post `Wrapper` class.

Comment: i made the changes ;)

Comment: Try to remove possible sources of error. Make an example which just does the following: Create a Wrapper instance, serializue it to a string, then desirialize it again.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that JSON.NET in .NET 4.5 would convert correctly the value that you have specified in your question.

Here is an example where i can get it working without issues when i deserialize to `List<DtoDirectory>`:

```
 var json = "[ { \"Name\": \"ANNONCES LEGALES\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ANNONCES LEGALES\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ANNONCES LEGALES\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ANNONCES LEGALES\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"DIVERS\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\DIVERS\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\DIVERS\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\DIVERS\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"ELECTIONS\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ELECTIONS\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ELECTIONS\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ELECTIONS\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"ETAT CIVIL\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ETAT CIVIL\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ETAT CIVIL\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ETAT CIVIL\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"URBANISME\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\URBANISME\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\URBANISME\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\URBANISME\\\\icon.png\" ] } ]";
 var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DtoDirectory>>(json);
```

Since you are using a `Wrapper` class in your example i suppose that you have some kind of Wrapper JSON object surrounding the JSON array in your example.

In that case your JSON would have to look like the following to work with your Wrapper class:

```
 var json = "{\"list\":[ { \"Name\": \"ANNONCES LEGALES\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ANNONCES LEGALES\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ANNONCES LEGALES\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ANNONCES LEGALES\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\CONSEIL MUNICIPAL\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"DIVERS\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\DIVERS\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\DIVERS\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\DIVERS\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"ELECTIONS\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ELECTIONS\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ELECTIONS\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ELECTIONS\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"ETAT CIVIL\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ETAT CIVIL\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ETAT CIVIL\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\ETAT CIVIL\\\\icon.png\" ] }, { \"Name\": \"URBANISME\", \"Path\": \"C:\\\\Test\\\\URBANISME\", \"DirectoryIcon\": [ \"C:\\\\Test\\\\URBANISME\\\\fond.png\", \"C:\\\\Test\\\\URBANISME\\\\icon.png\" ] } ]}";
 var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json);
```

What i am suspecting here is that the wrapper class does not reflect correctly the JSON structure that you are getting from the web service. So you should check the exact JSON Structure and build a Wrapper class that will correctly represent the JSON hierarchy of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Wrapper`, use `List<DtoDictionary>`

```
var test = SerializeHelper.Deserialize<List<DtoDictionary>>(lol);
```

After seeing your `Wrapper` class, I assume if you check what was the exception message on deserialization, you will see this

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Wrapper' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
>   deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
>   interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path '',
>   line 1, position 1.

By simply [googling](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Cannot+deserialize+the+current+JSON+array+(e.g.+%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D)+into+type+&safe=on) exception message, first 4 results would led you to SO similar questions that have answers how to solve the problem.

Comment: In any case, the same type must be used for Deserialize() as was used when Serialize() was called.

Comment: @bottus Could you please check [.netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u0JiVs) and tell what's the difference between your code and fiddle?

Comment: The main difference comes from the '\' i have in my json .. i tried your json (from jsfield) it works, i tried your by adding some  '\' in the paths and it doesn't work, with or without the @

Comment: @bottus Could you please modify [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u0JiVs#&togetherjs=GqOuSIqqzf) so that it will fail? I modified `json` string to include `\"` in `json` and it works.

Comment: i put my string in your example and it works but still doesn't in my code, i don't understand cause i have the same code than you .. https://dotnetfiddle.net/kQUVvq

Comment: it's getting ridiculous .. when i try to deserialize my string content, it doesn't work and throw and exception but when i put a break point, open the content viewer, copy the content of my string 'content' and put it in a new string it totally works ! i'm a bit lost i have to say ..

Comment: @bottus what's the version of `Newtonsoft.Json` you're using? In both cases - `fiddle` and in my local `VS2013` I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.0.0` and in both cases it works.